# To find temporary physical tables from database of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

The database which I'm using has **800+ physical tables**, some of which are backup / temporary tables which are not in use right now.

Is there any query to find out the temporary physical tables from the whole database?

Comment: How do you know they are "temporary"?

Comment: True temporary  tables have prefix '#' and are created in tempdb so what is 'temporary physical tables' from your question?

Comment: The scope of a temp table is the session. Once the session expires, you won't be able to find them.

Comment: temporary means those tables are not currently in used and we have created for backup purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no". First, there is no reliable way to identify is one table "backup/temporary" or it is "real data" table. SQL Server doesn't care why one table has been created.

One thing you can do is to use [index usage stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to identify the last time when some index in this table has been updated or read:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName
    , last_user_update
    , last_user_seek
    , last_user_scan
    , last_user_lookup
    , last_system_update
    , last_system_seek
    , last_system_scan
    , last_system_lookup
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
```

However, this isn't reliable. These stats are not persisted during restarts, so you may miss the last table usage. Also, you may have some automated index maintenance, which will rebuild the indexes and the table may look as used. Also, what if it is just rarely used? Only in the beginning of the year, to run a report for the last year?

Everything you can get are just hints what **maybe** unused. Go to your colleagues and ask. Rename tables and wait for someone to start screaming. But there is no reliable way to get such information.

Comment: >>>you may have some automated index maintenance, which will rebuild the indexes and the table may look as used<<< This case is easily identified by column last_**system**_scan as opposed to **user** seeks/scans

Comment: But you are correct about info durability of this view: it is reset not only on server restart, the simple change database status to offline will reset the view